# Improve SQL script

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to know if there is a better way to write the example script stated below.

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5y7T.png) has 1 line for every item.
[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpsU3.png) has 1 line for every physique available of an item.

I would write the SQL below. But when I have about 18 physique values, this will increase the join section. I can join the table without specifying the Physique, but this leaves me with a dataset where rows are exploded and I need to run a Distinct or Group By.

```
select 
    t2.ItemID, t2.Name, t1_width.Target as 'Width', t1_length.Target as 'Length'
from 
    t2 
    left join t1 as t1_width on t1_width.ItemID = t2.ItemID and t1_Physique = 'Width' 
    left join t1 as t1_length on t1_length.ItemID = t2.ItemID and t1_Physique = 'Length'
```

Maybe there is a better way to call the right values from the Select of make one join?

Answer (score 0):

You must use Pivot Table in this case. PIVOT basically changes the rows to columns. In this way there'd be only one INNER JOIN ON t1.ItemID = t2.ItemID.

To start with,

`SELECT DISTINCT Physique FROM table2`

to get the pivot (column values). There is even a set query to generate this in the example below.

[[Use this example to build the query]](https://%20https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/)

Quick Tip: You could use either MAX(target) or COUNT(target) in the agg func call in PIVOT table, depends on dataset you trying to generate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this helped me to reduce the amount of joins!

Comment: @Niek No worries, Kindly UPVOTE the answer so it can be useful for others :)

Comment: I need at least 15 reputations it seems to upvote it